# What is the equivalent of get('html') in mootools 1.11?

Tags: mootools

Can anyone tell me what is the equivalent of el.get('html') in mootools 1.11

Mootools 1.2 provides this get('html')

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: here is link to mootools 1.1 doc http://docs111.mootools.net/ doesn't seem like there's a getter for html but there's a `setHTML` or you can just go vanilla and do `el.innerHTML`

Answer (score 4):

by large, `get/set` were `getProperty/setProperty` (or properties) in 1.11 but there's no direct getter for html - `getProperty("html")` is not valid, neither is `getProperty('innerHTML')`.

to get, just do (it's still javascript!):

```
var html = $("someid").innerHTML;
```

you can build a chainable method that returns a string like so in 1.12:

```
Element.extend({
    getHTML: function() {
        return this.innerHTML;
    }

});

alert($("f").getHTML());
```

whereas in 1.2+ its Element.implements

you have setText and setHTML to set the innerHTML, as KJ pointed out.

and finally. you can enable the getter for getProperty that maps like so:

```
Element.Properties["html"] = "innerHTML";

console.log($("f").getProperty("html")); // works now.
```